# Destination Host Unreachable при создании Bridge

Tags: linux, сеть, bridge

В Альт Линукс пытаюсь создать bridge посредством etcnet (через NetworkManager тоже пытался)
Суть в чем:
есть интерфейс enp0s3, который получает по DHCP адрес из подсети 192.168.50.0/24
Но как только я поднимаю bridge компьютер теряет сеть и при пинге пишет Destination Host Unreachable
Настройка через etcnet такая:

```
/etc/net/ifaces/enp0s3
--options
```

внутри код:

```
TYPE=eth
DISABLED=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
CONFIG_IPV4=YES
```

Создаю виртуальный интерфейс vmbr0

```
/etc/net/ifaces/vmbr0
--ipv4address
--ipv4route
--options
--resolv.conf
```

в ipv4address:

```
192.168.50.111/24
```

в ipv4route:

```
default via 192.168.50.1
```

в options:

```
BOOTPROTO=static
CONFIG_WIRELESS=no
CONFIG_IPV4=yes
HOST='enp0s3'
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=bri
```

в resolv.conf

```
nameserver 77.88.8.8
```

Вывод команды ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master vmbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:55:a6:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe55:a6e8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:7e:a7:f4:9a:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.111/24 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::847e:a7ff:fef4:9a90/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

вывод ip r

```
default via 192.168.50.1 dev vmbr0 
192.168.50.0/24 dev vmbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.111
```

Пинг не проходит

```
PING 192.168.50.1 (192.168.50.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.50.111 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.50.111 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.50.111 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.50.111 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Если убираю мост и делаю просто подключение через enp0s3, через статику или DHCP, все работает.
Что я еще забыл указать?

Comment: а вы уверены что вопросто имеет отношение к `.NET`, если нет, пожалуйста, удалите тег